# How to copy values from one pointer to another

Tags: c++, pointers, android-ndk

I have the following pointer:

```
jfloat *verticesLocal;
```

And I want make a new copy to:

```
jfloat *vertices;
```

I want to copy the values from `verticesLocal` to `vertices`.

How can I do that? I've just tried the following command, but it doesn't work:

```
memcpy(vertices, verticesLocal, numVerticesLocal * sizeof(jfloat));
```

I can't see the error because I'm working with Android native code. Sorry.

Comment: Did you allocate space for vertices?  You should have done a calloc or malloc beforehand somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by copy a pointer? Just copy the value (address) or make a copy of the contents of whatever is pointed to?

Comment: I want to copy the values from `verticesLocal` to `vertices`.

Comment: The values from that `verticesLocal` points to, to the locations where `vertices` points to? If so, and they both point to sufficiently sized and aligned memory then your `memcpy` call is correct.

Comment: It works perfectly when I do a malloc before memcpy, as @aix and @lijie have suggested.

Comment: This is not copying pointers.  This is copying VALUES.  You copy a value that is pointed at in exactly the same way as one that is not.  You copy POINTERS by assigning the src to the destination just like you would with any other integral.

Comment: Sorry, but English is not my mother tongue. I make mistakes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`malloc` first, then do your `memcpy`.

Answer (score 57):

The idea of "copying a pointer", when taken literally, is nothing more than a simple assignment.

```
int x = 5;
int* p1 = &x;
int* p2 = p1; // there, we copied the pointer.
```

In this case, both `p1` and `p2` point to the same data - the `int` variable `x`.  However, because this is so trivial, I'm inclined to think that what you *really* are asking about is how to copy the *data* that the pointer points to.

In this case, it depends on the data type.  If the pointer points to a simple buffer of [PODs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c), this involves allocating a separate buffer, and then using something like `memcpy` (or preferably `std::copy`) to copy the data.  For example:

```
int* p1 = new int[100];
// ... fill p1 with values
int* p2 = new int[100]; // create a new buffer
std::copy(p1, p1 + 100, p2); // copy the data into p2
```

Or, you can use `memcpy` to copy the buffer byte-by-byte, since the buffer contains [PODs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c).

```
memcpy(p2, p1, 100 * sizeof(int));
```

However, if the pointed-to data is *not* a simple buffer, but rather a C++ object, you can't use `memcpy`.  You need to perform a *deep copy* of the object, (usually using the object's copy constructor) to get a clone of the object.  How this is done, or whether it's even possible, depends on the object.  (Some objects are noncopyable.)

I have no clue what a `jfloat` is, but if the object is, for example, an `std::string`, you would just do something like:

```
std::string* s1; // assume this points to a valid string
std::string* s2 = new std::string();
*s2 = *s1; // copies s1 using s2's assignment operator
```

In this contrived example it would be preferable to avoid heap-allocation altogether, and just use stack variables.  But it demonstrates the idea of copying a heap-allocated object.

Comment: You mentioned that some objects are noncopyable, when is this the case?

Comment: @Dennis, if the object has a `private` or `delete`d copy constructor, or contains any internal data members with `private` or `delete`d copy constructors, the object cannot be copied via the copy constructor.  An example of such an object is `std::fstream`; you cannot call `fstream::fstream(const fstream&)` - the compiler will generate an error.  In C++11 it can be moved, however.

Answer (score 4):

If you are copying the pointer, it is a simple assignment:

```
jfloat* verticesLocal; // assuming is is allocated already
jfloat* newVertices = verticesLocal;
```

IF you mean you want to copy the data the point points to, you have to allocate the memory for the new block of memory first:

// assume jfloat* verticesLocal is pointing to a valid memory block of size i

```
jfloat* newVertices = new jfloat[i];
memcpy(newVertices, verticesLocal, i * sizeof(jfloat));
```

Comment: See my comment to Nate, but that what you illustrate here is precisely the difference between a shallow copy and a deep copy.  Depending on your particular solution either may be applicable.

Comment: @SRM:  Which is why I provided both examples.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you copy an **array buffer** :

```
    unsigned char *pBufferSrc = new unsigned char[10];  
    unsigned char *pBufCpd = new unsigned char[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         pBufferSrc[i] = i;        // pBufferSrc = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]


     memcpy(pBufCpd, pBufferSrc, 10);   // data from pBufferSrc is copied to pBufCpd (0,1,2,..9)

     delete []pBufferSrc;       // if even pBufferSrc buffer gets deleted, pBufCpd still has the data
```